# rails routing does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-2

I have following route explicitly defined in my routes.rb

```
map.book_preview_v2 '/books/v2/:id', :controller => 'books', :action => 'show_v2'
```

But, in the logs, I see following message:

```
2015-09-25 16:49:04 INFO (session: f561ebeab121cd1c8af38e0482f176b8)
method /books/v2/519869.json (user: xxx:669052) params:
{"controller"=>"books", "action"=>"v2", "id"=>"519869",
"format"=>"json"}

ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded
to v2. Actions: some_method_1, some_method_2,
some_method_3, some_method_4, some_method_5, **show_v2**,
some_method_6, and some_method_7):
```

Am I missing some convention over configuration thing? Why in the logs I see action as "v2" instead of "show_v2"?

Comment: For the record, which version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to v2. Actions:
>   some_method_1, some_method_2, some_method_3, some_method_4,
>   some_method_5, **show_v2**, some_method_6, and some_method_7):
>
> Why in the logs I see action as "v2" instead of "show_v2"?

As per the [***Rails 2***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html) default route

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
```

it expects `v2` as `action` but you defined `show_v2` as `action` in the route. Changing your `route` to below should work

```
map.connect '/books/show_v2/:id', :controller => 'books', :action => 'show_v2'
```

Comment: That makes sense. Any other way I can keep my url as /books/v2/:id and my method name as show_v2?

Comment: @riship89 Wait. can you update your question with full `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

This is how to create [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html#regular-routes) for rails v2.3.8

Please revised the routes into.

```
map.connect '/books/v2/:id', :controller => 'books', :action => 'show_v2'
```

I hope It can help you.

Comment: Whats the theory behind it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't show the theory and documentation. I have updated my answer. In that documentation, you can find the detail description.
@eirikir: Thanks for your comments. I will be careful to write answer.

Comment: Thanks for help but not working. It is conflicting with rails convention and controller=>"books" action=>"v2" is being called.